# Bottom of the logo is cut off

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

At default (100%) zoom and scaling at 1920x1080 resolution, I am seeing the bottom of the new logo being cut off.  It's most noticeable on the curved letters ('C' and 'O'):

[image: screenshot]

I see this in all of the latest Chrome, Edge, IE, and Firefox on Windows 10.  In Chrome and Firefox it's the worst as it occurs at all zoom levels, but in the Microsoft browsers it seems to be fine at 125%:

[image]

I also see this in the latest Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 at 1440x900.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the reporting the issue. The problem was the logo wasn't pixel-snapped, so it was overflowing the logo box. (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

The logo will be updated with the next production build.